# Unable to load avatar(.glb) in mobiles

Tags: android, reactjs, mobile, webgl, babylonjs

We have our portal https://inzack.com  we have to login with Google credentials. After we login, the dashboard will display the avatar(.glb). This is working perfectly from any laptops(web).

If we login from Mobile device the avatar(.glb) is not loading inspite of having WEBGL compliant browser.
We checked the mobile settings as well... give permission for allowing the file to download.

We do not know what is the root cause of infinite loading from mobiles. pls suggest the way forward

Comment: I understood the root cause of problem, if we open the application from mobile the port 3000 is blocked as per the security constraints. Either change the port or enhance the security constraints in the mobile

Answer (score 0):

Actually its not the port issue...

The UI was not mobile compatible, the avatar was loading on the bottom of the UI controls which was not visible. The issue was fixed when the UI controls were adjusted accordingly.

Thanks